# My fetch command doesn't work, what did i do wrong?

Tags: reactjs

[image]im trying to fetch customers and trainings by using a fetch request but for some reason it doesn´t print anything in the page. However it is printing those informations in the network console.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import Addcustomer from "./Addcustomer";
import Addtraining from "./Addtraining";
import Editcustomer from "./Editcustomer";
import { AgGridReact } from'ag-grid-react'
import'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css'
import'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';

export default function Customerlist() {
   const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => fetchData(), []);

   const fetchData = () => {
       fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/customers')
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(data => setCustomers(data.content));
   };

   const deleteCustomer = link => {
       if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete customer?")) {
           console.log(link);
           fetch(link, { method: "DELETE" })
               .then(res => {

                   fetchData();
                   if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                       Snackbar({ message: "Customer deleted successfully" });
                   } else {
                       Snackbar({ message: "Error. Try again." });
                   }
               })
                   .catch(err => console.error(err));
       }
   };

   const saveCustomer = customer => {
       fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/customers', {
           method: "POST",
           headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
           body: JSON.stringify(customer)
       })
           .then(res => {
               fetchData();
               if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                   Snackbar({ message: "Customer added successfully" });
               } else {
                   Snackbar({ message: "Error. Try again." });
               }
           })
               .catch(err => console.error(err));
   };

       const saveTraining = training => {
       fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/trainings', {
           method: "POST",
           headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
           body: JSON.stringify(training)
       })

       .then(res => {
           fetchData();
           if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
               Snackbar({ message: "Training added successfully" });
               } else {
               Snackbar({ message: "Error. Try again." });
               }
           })
           .catch(err => console.error(err));
   };

       const updateCustomer = (customer, link) => {
       fetch(link, {
           method: "PUT",
           headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
           body: JSON.stringify(customer)
       })
           .then(res => fetchData())
           .then(Snackbar({ message: "Customer updated successfully" }))
           .catch(err => console.error(err));
   };

   const columns = [
       
       {
           title: "Edit",
           field: "links[0].href",
           render: customerData => (
           <Editcustomer updateCustomer={updateCustomer} customer={customerData} />
           ),
           sorting: false
       },
       {
           Header: "First name",
           accessor: "firstname"
       },
       {
           Header: "Last name",
           accessor: "lastname"
       },
       {
           Header: "Email",
           accessor: "email"
       },
       {
           Header: "Phone",
           accessor: "phone"
       },
       {
           Header: "Address",
           accessor: "streetaddress"
       },
       {
           Header: "Postcode",
           accessor: "postcode"
       },
       {
           Header: "City",
           accessor: "city"
       },
 {
           title: "Delete",
           field: "links[0].href",
           render: customerData => (
           
           <button
           style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
           onClick={() => deleteCustomer(customerData.links[0].href)}
           >Delete</button>
       ),
           sorting: false
   },
       {
           title: "Add training",
           render: trainingRow => (
           <Addtraining
               saveTraining={saveTraining}
               customerId={trainingRow.links[0].href}
               />
           ),
               sorting: false
       }
   ];

   return (
       <div>
           
           <Addcustomer saveCustomer={saveCustomer} />
           <AgGridReact
               title="Customers"
               rowData={customers}
               columns={columns}
               options={{ sorting: true }}
           ></AgGridReact>
       </div>
   );
}
```

i have multiple fetch requests for training and customers but its not working
it shows the information in the console but it doesn't show them in the page. I would like to see all the information in my page, so what i have to do or what did i do wrong here?

Comment: Can you describe the problem exacly? Did requests completed but is not printing anything?

Comment: In the browser, the network section shows that the fetch request retrieves the data from the console but does not print it to the page. i think there is probably a problem with the printing. There is the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The props passed to AgGridReact component are not the right type.

[`columnDefs` prop](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-definitions/#custom-column-types) is used to declare the column headers and should look like:

```
const columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'Customers',
    children: [
    {

      headerName: 'Edit',
      valueGetter: (params) => params.data.links[0].href,
      cellRenderer: (params) => <Editcustomer updateCustomer={updateCustomer} customer={params.data} />,
      sortable: false,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'First name',
      field: 'firstname',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Last name',
      field: 'lastname',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Email',
      field: 'email',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Phone',
      field: 'phone',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Address',
      field: 'streetaddress',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Postcode',
      field: 'postcode',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'City',
      field: 'city',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Delete',
      valueGetter: (params) => params.data.links[0].href,
      cellRenderer: (params) => (
        <button style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => deleteCustomer(params.data.links[0].href)}>
          Delete
        </button>
      ),
      sortable: false,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Add training',
      valueGetter: (params) => params.data.links[0].href,
      cellRenderer: (params) => (
        <Addtraining 
          saveTraining={saveTraining}
          customerId={params.data.links[0].href}
        />
      ),
      sortable: false,
    },
  ]
}];
```

[`defaultColDef` prop](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-definitions/#custom-column-types) is used to declare defaults for the column headers.

```js
const defaultColDef={ sortable: true }
```

Your implementation of the AgGridReact element should be:

```
          <AgGridReact
               rowData={customers}
               columnDefs={columnDefs}
               defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
           ></AgGridReact>
```

Finally, you need to either set the [domLayout prop](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-size/#grid-auto-height) so that the grid size is autocomputed (ideally for very small datasets).

```
          <AgGridReact
               rowData={customers}
               columnDefs={columnDefs}
               defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
               domLayout='autoHeight'
           ></AgGridReact>
```

Otherwise, you can set the size of the container element so that the grid size is computed from it.

```
    <div

       style={{
         height: '500px',
         width: '600px',
       }}
    >
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={customers}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
      ></AgGridReact>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can view here a running [stackblitz instance](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-at9kw3?file=App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

you need to conditionaly render the information when the data is ready and you need to map on every object

```
const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => fetchData(), []);

return (
  <>
    {customers && customers.map((obj, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
            <p>{obj.firstname}</p>
            <p>{obj.lastname}</p>
        </div>
    )}
  </>
)
```

your displaying data is more complicated because you use other components "Addcustomer", "AgGridReact" but im just showing how to basically get the data into html